# Cplex code/ Is this formula complex for cplex to calculate?

Tags: cplex

```
dvar boolean g[H][A][D][R];
dvar boolean count6[H][D];
dvar int cvsum6[H];
dvar int gap6;

//formula 1
forall(w in W, h in H)
  sum(a in A, r in R)(g[h][a][fourinsix[w]][r] + g[a][h][fourinsix[w]][r] + 
  g[h][a][(fourinsix[w]-2)][r] + g[a][h][(fourinsix[w]-2)][r]+ 
  g[h][a][(fourinsix[w]-3)][r] + g[a][h][(fourinsix[w]-3)][r]+ 
   g[h][a][(fourinsix[w]-5)][r] + g[a][h][(fourinsix[w]-5)][r]) 
   <= count6[h][fourinsix[w]]+3;

//formula 2
forall(w in W, h in H)
  sum(a in A, r in R)(g[h][a][fourinsix[w]][r] + g[a][h][fourinsix[w]][r] + 
  g[h][a][(fourinsix[w]-2)][r] + g[a][h][(fourinsix[w]-2)][r]+ 
  g[h][a][(fourinsix[w]-3)][r] + g[a][h][(fourinsix[w]-3)][r]+ 
   g[h][a][(fourinsix[w]-5)][r] + g[a][h][(fourinsix[w]-5)][r]) 
  >= 4*count6[h][fourinsix[w]];

//formula 3
forall(h in H)sum(w in W)count6[h][fourinsix[w]] == cvsum6[h];

//formula 4
forall(h in H)(max(h in H)cvsum6[h])-(min(h in H)cvsum6[h]) == gap6;
//formula 5
gap6 <= 2;
```

I set up a formula to schedule with a cplex solver.
In the formulas presented below, numbers 1 and 2 are equations that are set so that count6 becomes 1 when the left side is 4.

Equation 3 is the sum of the values of count6 for w, and numbers 4 and 5 are the constraints that the maximum-minimum difference of cvsum6 for each h must be less than 2.

When I add these formulas, I get the value I want, but the time to derive the solution is very long.
Is there a way to speed up the operation?..like changing the form of the formula.

There are so many formulas that are similar to these.

Please help me..I joined stackoverflow to ask this question..